# Add multiple records in one call Backendless

Tags: ios, objective-c, backendless

Can anybody help me, I have this loop, it works fine with few cycles but sometimes with big ones data is lost besides I don´t think this could be the best way to implement it....

```
for (int i = 0; i < [allTableData count]; i++) {
    item = [allTableData objectAtIndex:i];
    qut1.DocEntry = uuid;
    qut1.Status = @"O";
    qut1.ItemCode = item.code;
    qut1.Dscription = item.name;
    qut1.Quantity = item.quantity;
    qut1.UoM = item.uom;
    qut1.Price = item.price;
    qut1.LineTotal = item.linetotal;
    id<IDataStore> dataStore = [backendless.persistenceService of:[QUT1 class]];
    [dataStore save:qut1 responder:nil];
}
```

QUT1.h

```
@interface QUT1 : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectId;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *DocEntry;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Status;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ItemCode;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Dscription;
  @property (nonatomic) int Quantity;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *UoM;
  @property (nonatomic) double Price;
  @property (nonatomic) double LineTotal;
@end
```

Can anybody suggest a better solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could import data with CSV:
https://backendless.com/documentation/manage/mgmt_import.htm

Comment: HI @MarkPiller, that is not the idea, my App creates Sales Orders and the code above is applied to save items info, when an order has 5,10,15 items I have no problem but imagine an order with 60, 70, 80 or 90 items. Thanks for your response.

Comment: If your data structure is organized like this: "Order" >> has 0-to-N >> "OrderItem". Then in your code you create OrderItem objects, add them to the Order and then call "save" on the Order only 1 time. This way all of the objects (Order and OrderItem collection) will be saved with just one call.

Comment: All examples on this page demonstrate the approach: https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_relations_save_update.htm